# Grammatically, can you have a 'bit' of liquid?

Tags: grammar

Example:

There is a bit of wine left in the glass.

Comment: From the standpoint of grammar it's perfectly fine.  From the standpoint of logic you must judge yourself.

Comment: ... But the standpoint of usage is more relevant than either, and as Josh61 has pointed out, 'a bit' _is_ used informally to refer to a small amount of a liquid.

Comment: A 'bit' a wine never hurt nobody.

Comment: If you can pop out for a 'bit of fresh air', or a 'bit of peace and quiet', why not?

Comment: You may have a bit of wine.  "You've had enough; you may not have one bit more of wine."  You may have two bits of wine, which will be whatever 25 cents will buy you.  You can't have any larger number of bits of wine because liquid measures aren't measured in binary digits.  It is recommend that you have the hair of the dog that bit you.

Comment: And shpeak for yourshelf, Eva Little.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can have a little bit of wine (or other liquid).

Comment: You're 100% right, but on StackExhnge we do encourage answers to include a bit more discussion and corroboration rather than just a bald "yes" or "no". For example, you could talk about the relationship between quantifiers like "a bit" in relation to mass nouns vs count  nouns, etc.